# Not able to generate .exe file from a c program

Tags: c

I am trying to generate a .exe file the following program, which runs correctly but does not generate a .exe file. Instead it generates a .depend file.

---

I am using gcc compiler with CodeBlocks IDE on Windows 7 platform.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max(int  a,int b)
{
int c=(a>b)?a:b;
return c;
}

int maxCoins(int n)
{
int arr[n+1],i;
arr[0]=0;
arr[1]=1;
arr[2]=2;
arr[3]=3;

if(n>2)
{


for(i=3;i<=n;i++)
{
    int k= arr[(int)(i/2)]+arr[(int)(i/3)]+arr[(int)(i/4)];
    arr[i]=max(i,k);
}
}

 return arr[n];
}

int main(void)
{
int coins;

while((scanf("%d", &coins)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%d\n",maxCoins(coins));
}

getchar();

return 0;
}
```

---

What could be the problem ? I am able to compile other files easily. Does this has anything to do with the fact about how I am taking the input ?

Comment: I don't have an answer. But check this out: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=The_build_process_of_Code::Blocks#Using_project_dependencies

Comment: You're either looking in the wrong place or you have file extensions hidden